# How to get the sum total of the product of two fields across all the collections in mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a store inventory collection that contains "quantity" and "price" fields respectively

```
{
        "_id": "5dd033a1a9133424a8ae2924",
        "name": "Belt",
        "description": "Auto",
        "price": 7,
        "quantity": 60,
        "supplier": "Thomson",
        "taxable": true,
        "createdAt": "2019-11-16T17:36:33.753Z",
        "updatedAt": "2020-01-11T09:33:27.756Z",
        "__v": 0,
        "orders": []
    },
```

I want to be able to get the Total cost of all the items in the store i.e sum of price*quantity for all the item

```
// model

const mongoose= require('mongoose');


//create Schema
const InventorySchema = new mongoose.Schema({
   // _id: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
   name : { type: String, required: true },
   description : { type: String, required: true },
   price : { type: Number, required: true },
   quantity : { type: Number, required: true },
   supplier : String,
   taxable : Boolean,
   orders: [{quantity: Number,issuedBy:String,collectedBy:String,department:String}]

},{timestamps:true});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A simple `$group` stage should do the trick:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    {
        $group: { 
            _id: null,
            total: {$sum: {$multiply: ["$price", "$quantity"]}}
        }
    }
])
```

Comment: Hi, your solution return an error: "query failed: a group specification must include an _id"

Comment: Your right mb I forgot to add it as it's not relevant to the query, I edited it in

Comment: Thanks for your response, unfortunately i am getting the following ; CastError: Cast to ObjectId failed for value "cst" at path "_id" for model "Inventory" the "cst" is part of the path i am making use of the following path ''api/v1/inventory/cst''  i really dont know why the error is coming up ???

Comment: I already solved the issue, I simply moved the route path up my route list